# Почему Софию Лорен в России зовут Софи?

Tags: общие-вопросы

Ведь на родине она София. Откуда пошло это искажение?

Answer (score 1):

Это не искажение, это псевдоним. София Виллани Шиколоне - имя не очень звучное, кинокомпания предложила взять псевдоним, фамилию Лорен актрисе придумал продюсер Гоффредо Ломбардо - бросил взгляд на постер фильма с участием шведской актрисы Марты Торен и поменял в фамилии первую букву, а потом добавилось и Софи - на французский манер, и ударение стало вместо первого слога на второй. Это было ещё в 1953 году по настоянию Понти, будущего супруга. Обстоятельств было много, им было выгодно французское звучание по многим причинам.

Так что в России произносят настоящий псевдоним полностью, а в Италии её называют настоящим именем София, иногда сбиваясь на Софи - как на укороченное, ласково-фамильярное.

Comment: А есть зарубежные источники с укороченным именем? Мне не удалось найти.

Comment: @Людмила  Вы не правы. За рубежом её никто не называет Софи. Она везде София. Псевдоним касался только фамилии и, кстати, был не первым в карьере актрисы.

Comment: За попытку ответить, конечно, спасибо. Но у меня под рукой автобиография актрисы, где ни о каких "Софи" речь не идёт, включая эпизод с выбором фамилии-пседонима.

Comment: Один из авторов её биографии предполагает:
Сокращённое имя, произносимое на французский манер, приклеилось к актрисе с незапамятных времён, ещё на заре карьеры, когда в прокат пошли первые фильмы с её участием – уже под фамилией Лорен. Причём на родине, в Италии, её по-прежнему называют Софией. Софи она только за рубежом – в Соединенных Штатах (где Лорен необычайно популярна до сих пор), во Франции, в Швейцарии, у нас в России. https://biography.wikireading.ru/176047

Answer (score 1):

Могу только предположение высказать. По какой-то причине в английском варианте придуманной фамилии ударение оказалось на втором слоге (в итальянском варианте оно на первом, согласно английскому варианту википедии). На слух имя Sophia (наст. Sofia) *в слиянии* с такой трактовкой фамилии могло быть впервые воспринято из английского источника как "Софи Лорен", распространиться журналистами в таком виде и в дальнейшем закрепиться - в условиях скудности источников информации в те времена и отсутствия в советской прессе тенденции что-либо изменять без необходимости (написанное или произнесённое диктором имело тогда особый вес).